# Data not update when login is successfull in index.php?

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

[image]I make a login page like user login. if registered then login with email and password(navigate register.php to index.php page) or sign up if not registered. works good but i want to add update functionality in my index.php page concept is simple if user wants to update its record then he make updations in a form and submit. I make a update query here but its shows Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\LOginKodingMadSimple\index.php on line 34. Where i am wrong ?

index.php :

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include_once 'dbconnect.php';
?>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['UpdateUser'])) 
 {
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
   //------- name can contain only alpha characters and space -------
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) 
   {
     $error = true;
     $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
   } 
   //------- Update users -------
   if (!$error) 
   {
     if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET name='" . $name . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'")) 
   {
     $successmsg = "Successfully Updated! ";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $errormsg = "Error in Update...Please try again later!";
   }
  }
 }
 else
 {
   $errormsg = "Failed Please Try Again Later !";
 }
?>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) { ?>
        <li>
        <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?></p>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="updatephp.php">Update</a>
        </li>        
        <li>
        <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
        </li>                
        <div style="border:1px dashed transparent;margin-top:400px;position:absolute;margin-left:-35%;">
        <h1> Hello User <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?> ! </h1>
        <h1> Your Email is <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_email']; ?> ! </h1>

            <form action="" method="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?>"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" name="UpdateUser">
            </form>
       </div>

            <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NOTE**: You don't have any **textbox** named as `id.`]

Choose any way.

**Way 1)**

Change

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
```

To

```
$id = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['UpdateUser'])) {
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
  $id = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
```

**Way 2)**

Add one **hidden** input field having value `session usr_id`.

```
<form action="" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?>"><br>
      <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id'];?>" name='id'>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" name="UpdateUser">
</form>
```

In this way, your submitting form code will be same as you are having.

Comment: Cool its work the second option but it give a  Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\wamp\www\LOginKodingMadSimple\index.php on line 42

Comment: This error is not related to my code. Just you have to define $error after `if (isset($_POST['UpdateUser']))`

Answer (score 2):

add input hidden field with id like.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to hide the error notice :

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: But it hides notice.its fine but what about updation of data ? it's not update.

Comment: you do not have value in $id, you need to post the name and id both when submit the update form. just pass a hidden input field with the name id and value in your form

Comment: How can you please give a example ?